# How to sort list of lists ,by custom comparator, that hold extended classes?

Tags: java, sorting, compare, comparator, comparable

i can't seem to find a way to sort my list of list by "rent()" and "profit()". How can i achieve that?

Can't seem to find anything that would help.

Parent class:

```java
public abstract class Zone
{
    int area; //zonos plotas kv metrais
    float price; //kaina uz kv metra
    int jobPlaces; //darbo vietu skaicius
    abstract float rent();
    abstract float profit();
    abstract float expenses();
    abstract float totalProfit();
}
```

I have 3 classes (Residential, Commercial, Industrial) that extend this class and overrides its abstract methods.

I define lists:

```java
static ArrayList<Zone> coll1 = new ArrayList<Zone>();
static ArrayList<Zone> coll2 = new ArrayList<Zone>();

static ArrayList<ArrayList<Zone>> superCollection = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Zone>>();
```

Then i randomly (ex. 3 Residential zones, 5 Commercial zones, 1 Industrial zone) fill coll1 and coll2 and add them to superCollection.

How could i sort superCollection by "rent()" print it and then sort it by "profit()" by ascending or descending order?

Edit:

```
Collections.sort(superCollection, new Comparator<ArrayList<Zone>>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(ArrayList<Zone> arg0, ArrayList<Zone> arg1)
    {
        return arg0.get(0).profit().compareTo(arg1.get(0).profit());
    }
});
```

Tried running this, but it stil doesn't sort by profit:

```
zone                 rent           profit                          
Residential zone:   11578.3         5534.4             
Residential zone:    1963.7         2935.1              
Residential zone:    4029.5         4987.2             
Residential zone:   13399.6        11453.7             
Residential zone:    2763.7         7212.9              
Residential zone:    3961.3         3384.8                  
Commercial zone:    29041.3        59291.3             
Commercial zone:    10483.6        42842.5             
Industrial zone:    48332.3       939667.0          
Industrial zone:    31563.8      1074516.2            
Residential zone:    8347.1         3587.1                 
Commercial zone:    26177.9        47750.9            
Industrial zone:    33917.8      1005413.1            
Industrial zone:    25704.2      1251655.3            
Industrial zone:    30268.5      1131300.0             
Industrial zone:    42225.1       588861.8                            
Industrial zone:    32779.2      1220447.5          
Industrial zone:    19686.2       863131.5
```

Comment: Hi @Dziugas, welcome to https://stackoverflow.com .Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to write variables in English,so that users can guess its values.

Comment: Edited variable names , should be easier imagine what i'm trying to achieve , unless you still need sample data?

Comment: An example might help, because the question from Arnaud still stands: what is the desired order of your list of lists? Each sorted individually and then the outer list by the first elements? Or averages, maybe?

Comment: Do you actually need a list of list, or could you just add all of your zones to a single list?

Comment: I need to sort the list of lists. I added data sample , it should be clearer what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Are you certain your "superset" isn't supposed to be `ArrayList<Zone>`, but with all the other lists' zones added to it?  Your desired results seem to indicate that...

Comment: I need to make 2 lists of random zones and add those lists to super list then sort super list by profit of those zones and print it , then sort it by rent and print it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to printed lists sorted two different ways you'll need two comparators.  Combine the list from the super collection into a single list, sort it using the first comparator, print it, sort it with the second comparator, then print it again.

```
private Comparator<Zone> rentComparator = new Comparator<Zone>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Zone o1, Zone o2) {
            Float o1Rent = o1.rent();
            Float o2Rent = o2.rent();

            return o1Rent.compareTo(o2Rent);
        }
    };

private Comparator<Zone> profitComparator = new Comparator<Zone>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Zone o1, Zone o2) {
            Float o1Rent = o1.profit();
            Float o2Rent = o2.profit();

            return o1Rent.compareTo(o2Rent);
        }
    };

public void printSortedLists(List<List<Zone>> superCollection) {

    List<Zone> combinedList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<Zone> list : superCollection) {
        combinedList.addAll(list);
    }
    Collections.sort(combinedList, rentComparator);

    //TODO now print the rent sorted list here

    Collections.sort(combinedList, profitComparator);

    //TODO now print the profit sorted list here
}
```

Comment: I tried to edit your code to suit my need (Edit 2), but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Ah, I posted this before you edited. The question has changed and this won't work.  If I have time I'll come back and fix it.

Comment: @DziugasPetkevicius If I understand the problem correctly this time this should do it.  If not you should be able to piece together an answer using these concepts.

Comment: There are two Collections.sort methods.  One just takes a list, the other takes a list and a comparator.  Wherever you are calling Collections.sort from needs to have access to the comparator.

Comment: I added my comparator, can you please check it?

Comment: You're only comparing the first item in each list with your comparator.  You need to combine the lists in the supercollection into a single list and sort the combined list if you want a sorted list of all zones.  The code I wrote should do that, the only thing I didn't provide was the code that prints the list, I just left comments where that needs to be done.